# How to write a type definition file for a default exported class?

Tags: node.js, typescript, type-definition

I'm trying to write a type definition file for [OpenSubtitles.org api node wrapper](https://github.com/P0oOOOo0YA/opensubtitles-api). Here is the main file [index.js](https://github.com/P0oOOOo0YA/opensubtitles-api/blob/master/index.js). On line 7 the `OpenSubtitles` class is exported as module's default export.

```
module.exports = class OpenSubtitles {
....
}
```

So i came up with the following

```
declare module "opensubtitles-api" {
  export default class OpenSubtitles {
  }
}
```

This is the transpilation of a code using `OpenSubtitles.org api node wrapper` and my .d.ts file.

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var opensubtitles_api_1 = require("opensubtitles-api");
var os = new opensubtitles_api_1["default"]({
    useragent: "TemporaryUserAgent"
});
```

and when i run it. I get this error.

```
var os = new opensubtitles_api_1["default"]({
         ^

TypeError: opensubtitles_api_1.default is not a constructor
```

When i remove the `["default"]` part of the transpiled code everying work as expectd.

### Desired transpilation

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var opensubtitles_api_1 = require("opensubtitles-api");
var os = new opensubtitles_api_1({
    useragent: "TemporaryUserAgent"
});
```

How should i export/declare `OpenSubtitles` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default exports are different from when you are replacing the whole export object. The syntax for that is :

```
declare module "opensubtitles-api" {
   class OpenSubtitles {
   }
   export = OpenSubtitles
}
```

Comment: Sadly. The same result `opensubtitles_api_1["default"]`.

Comment: @pouya how do you import? `import OpenApi = require( 'opensubtitles-api')
new OpenApi();` this should work.

Comment: Thaks, that did the job. I was using `import OpenSubtitles from 'opensubtitles-api'`. Why changing to `require` made the code to be transpiled correctly?

Comment: @pouya the new `import` syntax does not support this kind of replacing the export object import as far as I know.